# Query id presence in a long list

Tags: solr

I have a use case where I need to create a Solr query that among other things has to check is an id is in a long list of ids. Think about something like

```
fq = balance:[* TO 100] AND id:("00003","00004","00006", … about 50K ids … , "87934")
```

50K is not something precisely defined, I just use it to explain the scale.

What is the best way to implement this? Should I just increase `maxBooleanClauses` in the config to 50K, or its better to use the field(term) query parser? Are other people dealing with such issues in Solr, or its not feasible at all?

Answer (score 1):

you could go with increasing maxBooleanClauses, it's easy and quick to implement, and will probably work up to a point, maybe it works for you in all cases....

if at some point you need something more you probably need to implement a [PostFilter](https://lucidworks.com/2015/05/15/custom-security-filtering-solr-5/), that should work for you